# How do I style an elements inside the navlinks when the navlinks got activated?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

how do I style the background of `<li>` elements inside of the `<NavLink>`

```
<ul>
            <NavLink  activeStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff', fontSize: '19px'}} exact to="">
                <li>Home</li>
            </NavLink>
           
            <NavLink activeStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff', fontSize: '19px'}} exact to="/about">
                <li>About</li>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink activeStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff', fontSize: '19px'}} exact to="/contact">
                <li>Contact</li>
            </NavLink>
        </ul>
```

right now I've been trying to use the `activeStyle` but isn't going well for me cause maybe it styled the `<a>` tag. Can you style the background of `<li>` tag with `<NavLink>` active style or maybe there is a workaround to this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **activeClassName** property:

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="selected">
  ...
</NavLink>
```

Comment: How does that work?. I've read the documentation its says that `activeClassName ` "The class to give the element when it is active" which means it's just a different way of using `activeStyle` or maybe I'm wrong and there's more to it?

Comment: to style li element you should use "selected" className:
.selected li {
  background: red;
}